# Applescript Error "can't get end of"

Tags: macos, applescript, average

I am trying my hand at Applescript and can't see anything wrong with this.
The Error I get is

error "Can’t get end of {button returned:\"OK\", text returned:\"3\"}." number -1728 from last insertion point of {button returned:"OK", text returned:"3"}

This is my code:

```
beep
set counter to 0
set tempX to 0
set temp to 0
set counting to 0
set stored to {0}
set input to "How many grades do you wish to enter?" as string
set str to display dialog input buttons {"NEXT"} default button "NEXT" default answer ""
repeat text returned of str times
    counting = counting + 1
    set grades to display dialog "GRADES:  " default answer ""
    set stored to grades
end repeat
set rep to the length of stored
repeat rep times
    counter = counter + 1
    set tempX to the ((end of stored) - counter) as number
    set temp to temp + tempX
end repeat
set ln to the length of grades
set average to temp / ln
if text returned of str is 1 then
    say "The Average of your grade is " & average using "Zarvox"
else
    say "The Average of your grades is " & average using "Zarvox"
end if
get "AVERAGE:  " & average
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, before I begin: I'd strongly recommend that you teach yourself how to use the Javascript interface to Apple Events, rather than the Applescript language itself. Applescript is a *really weird* language, and its quirks are largely unique; learning it is going to be frustrating, and won't help you learn other languages.

That being said, let's dive into your code:

```
set stored to {0}
```

This would start you out with one grade that's always present and set to zero. You probably want to just initialize this to an empty list:

```
set stored to {}
```

---

Next:

```
set grades to display dialog "GRADES:  " default answer ""
```

This sets `grades` to a *result object*, not just the answer. What you probably want here is actually the `text returned` of the result:

```
set grades to text returned of (display dialog "GRADES:  " default answer "")
```

(This is what's creating the really weird-looking object in your error message.)

---

Next, you overwrite `stored` with this result object:

```
set stored to grades
```

What you probably want here is to insert this element into the list. Because Applescript is a strange and obnoxious language, this is somewhat more cumbersome than you're thinking:

```
set stored to stored & {grades}
```

---

Finally, there's some logical issues with your averaging; you're adding the `end of stored` (that is, the last grade input) to the `temp` variable each time. A much simpler approach would be:

```
set temp to 0
repeat with n in stored
    set temp to temp + n
end repeat
set average to sum / (count of stored)
```

---

With these changes all made, your script should work correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have spent the past like 4 hours frustrated with this.  I've never seen that "repeat with n" before though.  But still, thank you so much.

Comment: I just want to add one thing, and that is that any word that turns up in blue is a keyword, and can't be used as a variable name. Your use of ln, turns blue on my machine. The way to fix this is to change the name of course, but you can also write it like this `|ln|` to tell the interpreter that it is your variable. I also recommend you download and read a little in AppleScript Language Guide. (free)

Comment: @McUsr: That is of course arguable, for a clean mac without having all kind of arbitrary osaxen and script libraries installed `ln` can be used properly without the need of pipes around them. Or at least tell which commercial osax is causing the problem. Now the comment is more or less meaningless

Comment: Actually not, because some coloured word may turn up at some time, and then the op hopefully knows how to deal with the situation.

Comment: `ln` is used by the Satimage osax. In the Smile script editor, you can type `ln`, compile, then do a command-shift-f to reveal the definition, which, in this case, brings up `ln` as a command which returns base-e logarithm of a real number.

Comment: **Amendment:** " ... compile, select the 'blue' text, then do a command-shift-f ... "